# Does winpcap and sharppcap support the pcap-ng format

Tags: wireshark, pcap, libpcap, winpcap, sharppcap

I've a file in the pcapng format and want to open it by SharpPcap - that doesn't work.

SharpPcap uses Winpcap (libpcap).

So my question: 
Does WinPcap and/or SharpPcap support the pcap-ng format at the moment or in future? I can't find some current information about it, only some old posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does WinPcap and/or SharpPcap support the pcap-ng format at the moment

No.  Support for reading pcap-ng files was added to libpcap in libpcap 1.1.0, and the latest WinPcap is based on libpcap 1.0.0.

> or in future?

Hopefully some future WinPcap release will be based on a recent libpcap release.  This will require some work, mainly for remote-capture support with the new `pcap_create()`/`pcap_activate()` APIs.

Comment: I can't find a source that shows me on which libpcap version the current WinPcap based. Do you have one? :)

Comment: Yes.  It's [the WinPcap source code](http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpcapSrc_4_1_3.zip).

Comment: This answer is not actual

Comment: I'd like to mention that this hasn't been the case for a number of years now, sharppcap has supported pcap-ng for some time now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65694772/299037

Answer (score 0):

To read timestamp with nanosecond precision

1. Update original WinPcap setup with [WinPcap 4.1.3 - libpcap 1.7.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpcap413-176/)
2. Open file using `pcap_open_offline_with_tstamp_precision`  function and pass `PCAP_TSTAMP_PRECISION_NANO` as a second parameter.
3. After that your app should treat `pcap_pkthdr::ts` structure returned from `pcap_next` as a seconds+nanoseconds.

Sorry, I did not have chance to port it to SharpPcap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SharpPcap supports the latest libpcap and npcap releases and these releases support pcap-ng file format.